# {Javascript} dropdown menu (with submenus) stays open when opening another menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question about JS dropdown menus.
I have multiple menus button, each has submenus. Unfortunatly once I open a menu, it stays open even if I click on another menus buttons and they visually overlap.
I´ve tried different solutions found on here, but apparently I´m doing something wrong.
Here is what I have:

```
   $( '.main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a, .main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a, .widget_nav_menu .page_item_has_children > a, .widget_nav_menu .menu-item-has-children > a' ).append( '<button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"/>' );
$( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).toggleClass( 'toggle-on' );
    $( this ).parent().next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggle-on' );
    $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
} );
```

And:

> ```
> jQuery(document).ready(function($){
>     $(window).resize(function(){
>          var socialHeight = $('.social-icons').outerHeight();
>          $('.social-icons').css('margin-top',-(socialHeight/2));
>     }).resize();
> });
> ```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: P.S. the .hover funciton to make menus open only when the mouse hovers over them isn´t an option since it woundn´t work on mobile devices.